# JSP and Tomcat webpage running issues

Tags: jsp

I want to publish my jsp pages created on the win 7 machin located on the local pc.When am running the project. It runs but not display that page in browser.
please help me..

Comment: Sounds like you didn't package or deploy the app properly.  What does the Tomcat log say?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat has a admin guy showing installed apps and state. if the app is not deployed for some reason you will see it there.